# Find link on webpage

Tags: html, objective-c, download

I have a google webpage, with a search already loaded, and I need to find the first link on the webpage and get the information(the brief summary) under the link. I imagine that this requires some sort of HTML download of the webpage, and then a search through that file for a link tag, but I have no idea how to get a HTML file off of a webpage and save it using Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a HTML file off a webpage is very easy to do, just use NSStrings method +stringWithContentsOfURL:

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(error)
{
   // oh, thats bad
}
```

Then you can search for the first link e.g. by using -rangeOfString

```
NSRange rangeOfLink = [html rangeOfString:@"bla"];

if (rangeOfLink.location == NSNotFound) 
{
  // that's bad, too
}
```